# EF-Core: loading related data into a string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-key-relationship

In our `ASP.NET Core 1.1` with `EF Core 1.1 app`, we've a scenario similar to the following: Parent table `PT` and child table `CH` have 1-1 FK-relationship. We need to get a few columns from certain records from `PT` table, and a few columns from associated records from the `CH` table. **Question**: How can we load these records to a comma delimited string? The following code loads these related records to a `ViewModel`.

**Note:** If we were to load records - into a comma delimited string - only from, say, `PT` we would do the following:

```
string csv = string.Concat(
                 PT.Select(
                        p => string.Format("{0},{1},{2}\n", p.PTCol1, p.PTCol2, p.PTCol3)));
```

**PT**:

```
public class PT
{
  Public int PTId {get; set;}
  Public int PTCol1 {get; set;}
  Public string PTCol1 {get; set;}
  Public float PTCol1 {get; set;}
  ....
  public CH ch { get; set; }
}
```

**CH**:

```
public class CH
{
  Public int CHCol1 {get; set;}
  Public string CHCol2 {get; set;}
  ....
  public int? PTId { get; set; }
  public PT pt { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class PT_CH_ViewModel
{
   Public int PTCol1 {get; set;}
   Public string PTCol1 {get; set;}
   Public float PTCol1 {get; set;}
   ....
   Public int CHCol1 {get; set;}
   Public string CHCol2 {get; set;}
....
}
```

**Controller:** Need to load to a comma delimited string here

```
var pts = _context.PT
                .Include(p => p.CH)
                .Where(p => p.PTcol == selectedID)
                .Select(pt => new PT_CH_ViewModel()
                {
                    PTCol1 = pt.Col1,
                    PTCol2 = pt.Col2,
                    PTCol3 = pt.Col3,
                    CHCol1 = pt.CH.Col1,
                    CHCol2 = pt.CH.Col2
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using linq-to-entities:

```
var pts = (from pt in context.PT
          join ch in context.CH on pt.PTId equals ch.PTId
          select new {
              PTCol1 = pt.Col1, 
              CHCol1 = ch.CHCol1
              // select other columns here...
          }).ToList();

var ptsStringCollection = pts.Select(p => string.Format("{0},{1}", p.PTCol1, p.CHCol1);
```

Comment: I've marked your response as an Answer. You may want to add newline character `\n` in `string.Format("{0},{1}", p.PTCol1, p.CHCol1);` of your code. Thanks.